# Create input for cvContourArea in JavaCV

Tags: opencv, javacv, javacpp

How to create the contour to pass to cvContourArea? I have four 2D points, but don't know to create the CvSeq.

```java
int[] myPolygon = new int[] { point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y, ... };
cvCountourArea(???, null, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```java
int[] myPolygon = new int[] { point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y, ... };
Mat rectMat = cvCreateMat(1, myPolygon.length/2, CV_32SC2);
rectMat.getIntBuffer().put(myPolygon);
cvCountourArea(rectMat, CV_WHOLE_SEQ, 0);
cvReleaseMat(rectMat);
```